# mat-step content vanishes when animating - mat-horizontal-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

Noticed some weird behavior when using [Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api) combined with container animations.

if you click a step, while the mat-stepper is animating, the content of the step goes invisible.

**HTML:**

```
<strong> reload - while the stepper is fading in - spam click step 2 </strong>.

<mat-horizontal-stepper [@fadeAnimation]>
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP ONE CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP TWO CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP THREE CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**Animation:**

```
function fadeAnimation() {
  return trigger('fadeAnimation', [
    state('void', style({})),
    state('*', style({})),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({ opacity: 1 }),
      animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phv4ll-yofegh?file=src/app/stepper-overview-example.html)

is there a possible workaround for this ?
(other than `[@.disabled]` of course, the animation is still wanted.)

Comment: For which browser you are getting issue ? Chrome I am able to see content on all 3 steps.

Comment: chrome. reload the [demo](https://angular-phv4ll-yofegh.stackblitz.io/) and WHILE it fades in, spam click step 2. you will see it vanishes. I increased animation time to 2s, should make it more obvious.

Comment: Some issue with visibility:visible. If you look at computed styles tab in chrome . It will show you visibility:hidden, Though it should compute it as visibility:visible after completion of animation.

Comment: Use `visibility` style also with `opacity `

Comment: have the same problem, but i'm triggering steps programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work. At least for me. Please try if it fits your needs. See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/animations-go-crazy?file=src/app/stepper-overview-example.ts).

Basically I gave the `fadeAnimation` a trigger with the specific states: `visible` and `hidden`.

The default value is `hidden`. Then the trigger is set to visible only when the `stepTransition` from `mat-stepper` is done. There is a `(animationDone)` event we can listen on.

This was the only way how I could sequence these two animations, which before clearly messed up the visibility state.
For me it only worked if the `fadingAnimation` was triggered after the `stepTransition` animation from Angular Material. I tried to use `query` and `stagger` but it did not work quite correct.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
  animations: [fadeAnimation()]
})
export class StepperOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  fadeTrigger = 'hidden';

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  stepperDone() {
    console.log('stepper is done now');
    this.fadeTrigger = 'visible';
  }
}

function fadeAnimation() {
  return trigger('fadeAnimation', [
    state('hidden', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    state('visible', style({ opacity: 1 })),

    transition('* => visible', [
      animate('2s ease-in-out'),
    ]),
    transition('visible => *', [
      animate('1s ease-in-out')
    ])
  ]);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [@fadeAnimation]="fadeTrigger" (animationDone)="stepperDone()">
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP ONE CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP TWO CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <p>STEP THREE CONTENT</p>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

[Link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/stepper/stepper-animations.ts) to source ofMatStepper animation.

[Link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/stepper/stepper.ts#L158) to source of Stepper.